# MySQL syntax Error on Create Trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mysql-error-1064

Here is my trigger, I am getting the MySQL syntax error. I wanted to reduce the balance from sms_index *table* sms_count *column* value.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER sms_log_update AFTER UPDATE ON sms_index
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.approved_status = '1' THEN
      UPDATE  sms_package SET  balance =  (balance - OLD.sms_count) WHERE  group_id = OLD.ins_group_id;
    END IF;
  END;
```

**Error Message:**

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: You may not have set delimiters If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.-https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks correct, except for the possible problem of the delimiter.  Try the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sms_log_update AFTER UPDATE ON sms_index
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.approved_status = '1' THEN
        UPDATE  sms_package SET  balance =  (balance - OLD.sms_count)
        WHERE  group_id = OLD.ins_group_id;
    END IF;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> However, just as for stored routines, if you use the mysql program to define a trigger that executes multiple statements, it is necessary to redefine the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger definition.

Comment: now I am getting just "Error" no error id and error type. is it the problem with MySQL version?

Comment: I see no errors in the trigger I wrote above.  Try running an empty trigger and see what happens.  If an empty trigger still generates an error message then something else is at work here.

Comment: I generate the Trigger from PHPMyadmin its works, I'll check the generated query, it doesn't have the Begin and End comment. do you know why?

Comment: Good question...I don't know why.

Comment: oh my god, you are saying don't know, your Reputations says you are "G" :)

Comment: @Muthu To the contrary, if I hear someone on the site say I don't know, it lets me know I'm talking to a serious computer scientist.  I have little experience with tools which generate MySQL code.